# Почему при изменении высоты div, весь контент скачет в сторону?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть div, который изменяет свою высоту с помощью javascript после нажатия на этот же div.
Почему при изменении высоты весь контент сайта слегка скачет в сторону?

[Вот здесь это замечено](http://goo.gl/MbG2J), "рубрики" в левом меню

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что появляется вертикальная полоса прокрутки. Высота самого сайта при загрузки маленькая, поэтому полосы прокрутки нет, если середина будет заполнена контентом, такого эффекта не будет. Если хотите побороть это, нужно рыть в сторону [overflow-x](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow-x)

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего решить - добавить в файл my.css

```
html {
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

А скачет он потому, что при увлечении высоты дива, появляется полоса прокрутки справа, а так как все содержимое сайта находится в блоке <center> происходит рецентровка, в следствии чего всё содержимое сайта сдвигается влево на половину ширины скроллбара.

Answer (score 0):

Запускал на Опере версия:11.51, сборка:1087 - не скачет, всё работает чётко.

В Хроме хуже - после первой загрузки странице и первом клике по блоку он разворачивается чётко (остальные контент не скачет), но при повторном клике (при сворачивании) блок не изменяет своей высоты, а лишь пропадает его содержимое.

Предположу что Ваш JS код не во всех браузерах работает правильно.